# When regression is run on population

Tags: regression, finite-population

I have  a small population and it is possible to estimate  Population regression function from the data. The size of the population is very small. It is only eight. I think since the regression  relates to poulation, there is no need to conduct any testing. Am I correct?

Comment: What sort of tests are you doing?  Is the population fixed over time (e.g. are there births and deaths)?

Comment: Even if you have the whole population, we typically think of those as a sample of a larger *hypothetical* population. Eg, imagine studying a rare disease where you have access to every person alive w/ the disease. It's still possible that some different people will have the disease in the future.

Comment: Q&A with similar issues at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/statistical-inference-when-the-sample-is-the-population.  Generally it actually fits in well with a lot of questions of interest to approach the actual observation as a sample generated by an infinite data generating process or infinite population.  But it depends what you are looking for.