# Type II error relevant limitation when Kaplan-Meier curves are identical?

Tags: type-i-and-ii-errors, kaplan-meier

Let's suppose that we have a made-up data including two diseases, and one of them is very rare (impossible to get a large sample size). Kaplan-Meier curves of the two diseases are almost identical, showing that the mortality of the two diseases is similar (Logrank test p = 0.5).

Type II error is a case where there is not enough statistical power to identify the difference between study groups. Mostly due to low sample size. Thus, Logrank test p-value may be insignificant due to the small n of rare disease group.

**But is the type II error relevant limitation in such case?** The Kaplan-Meier curves are identical, showing that the mortality after both diseases is similar not in terms of statistical testing, but in terms of their crude survival rates.

Or let's suppose both groups include 5 million patients, statistical testing may find a clinically meaningless difference (e.g. 1-2%).

**Isn't it so that in all cases the data speaks the same story - similar mortality between the two groups?**

[image]

Comment: You are confusing samples with populations and thinking that type II probabilities have something to do with observed data.  They don't.  Type II assertion probabilities are long-run operating characteristics that depend on having infinitely many identically distributed samples.  Also remember that in samples you can get agreement in survival curves by chance even where there is a population difference.

Comment: But does the answer differ when I do have population-wide data? Is type II error relevant then?

Comment: You might want to think over the extensive discussion on [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2628/28500) about situations when you think that your sample is the entire population of interest.