# Can we run ANOVA for estimates?

Tags: anova

So , I am currently working as an Intern for Government Statistical Organization that does sample surveys & presents estimates on various aspects.  My work is to present some statistical analysis using data from  the published reports . Can I run ANOVA to check for difference between means for different groups in this scenario? Your answer will greatly solve my doubt .

Comment: You should probably find someone knowledgeable to ask within the organization. That is too large a question to be asked here.

Comment: I add to my question , can I do any hypothesis testing to such kind of datas ?

Comment: Yes, is the short answer. But your questions are much too vague. Whole books have been written about testing hypotheses of differences between means using anova. You are not going to get good answers to questions that need a book to answer them. :)  Try to be more specific?

Comment: To be specific you do hypothesis testing on sample datas. But estimates are done by organization to avoid census . So ,in short the data is almost equal to data from census. How can I even do hypothesis testing on data that is exactly population data ?

Comment: This final question comes up often. E.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/statistical-inference-when-the-sample-is-the-population

Comment: But you're in a government statistics organization? You can't be the first person to have this problem. You should ask someone.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing the answer.  I really did ask and they said it's all right to do since my data is on situation of farmers in 2013 and 2019.  Thank you.